# Get content between comments in Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, comments, scrapy, block

I am trying to get the content betweens comments via Scrapy. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21830812/scrapy-extract-commented-hidden-content) already but didn't get further than only extracting the comments this way. My goal though is to get everything between the 2 comments, for every time "start comment" and "end comment" occur. Let's say the blocks on the website are structured like this:

```
<!-- Start -->
<div class.. >
    <ul>...
        more content
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- End -->

<!-- Start -->
    same structure, different entries
<!-- End -->

<!-- Start -->
    same structure, different entries
<!-- End -->
....
```

What I am looking for is something that works like xpath to find specific strings and saves them all in a list and would get an output that is somewhat similar to "[contentBlock1, contentBlocks2, ...]", just the way you usually get the output using xpath. Anything that helps in any way is highly appreciated :)

Edit: It might be worth noting that I am currently working with a scrapy response/selector object. A solution being able to handle either would be preferred.

Comment: http://www.gelbeseiten.de/programmierung/berlin
Blocks are from <!-- Start m08... > to <!-- Ende m08...>

Comment: so you want all the html between the comments?

Comment: Yep, exactly that. I have everything to filter the content afterwards, but would need the block structure and the blocks individually to get reliable information from it.

Comment: Do the comments at least have to start with START or ENDE? So other comments that don't match that are ignored?

Comment: try this http://pastebin.com/P38FdzS6

Comment: I posted this in another comment: http://pastebin.com/hLygUE0p

Just tried out yours and seems to be exactly what I need  :)

Comment: good, I tested a little and it seemed to work but there was way too much data to test it all!

Comment: Re-wrote the filters (were based on xpath before, but BeautifulSoup is more beautiful) and it's working without any flaws so far :) Thank you again.

Just one little question, about the code: What exactly does `(".//following-sibling::div[1]")` do?

Comment: it basically just gets the first div after the comment starting with START m8, if you play around with it using text() instead of div[1] yo will see different results

Answer (score 0):

something like response.xpath('.//*[@id="your id here"]/ul/text()').extract() should do it

Comment: Not working yet, probably because I am wondering how this going to recognize where the block ends. Also what is "id" since there is no id directly set or does scrapy allow you to just set a comment = id?

Comment: sorry, <div class='foo bar'> should be matched by //div[\@class='foo'] so change '@id' by '@class'.

Comment: Oh, I think it was not clear enough then. I really have to filter by the comments, not classes, since the class names change and/or are also in use for blocks that I don't want to work with.

Comment: since you had the same structure message I assumed you had same class name for every comment. could you post a "real" html example maybe, that would help :)

Comment: Yeah, I understand the confusion but I assumed "between comments" would be clear enough :P 
Copied an example here: http://pastebin.com/hLygUE0p
<!-- START m08_teilnehmer_treffer.jsp -->
<!-- ENDE m08_teilnehmer_treffer.jsp -->

Answer (score -1):

If you are willing to use `re` you can try this.

```
print re.findall(r"(?<=<!-- Start -->\s)(.*?)(?=\s<!-- End -->)",test_string,re.DOTALL)
```

This will return a list containing what you want.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/17

Comment: Yeah, I was already experimenting with the re module and that seems pretty logical. What does the "test_string" variable stand for exactly? Using what I get from the selector directly is not working here (of course, it is not really a string).

Comment: @Shin the whole of the content has to be in string.What is your input of form?can we convert it into string?

Comment: As mentioned, I am using Scrapy. The of response from `yield Request("url", def)` is <class'scrapy.http.response.html.HtmlResponse'> , using `Selector(response)` returns <class 'scrapy.selector.unified.Selector'>. Both no strings and not sure if it would make sense to somehow create a string out of it. Will look into it.