# Why can't scrapy find table using XPath given the ID?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm sort of new to programming, but I've been following this Scrapy tutorial to scrape NFL data here: http://brutalsimplicity.github.io/2016/07/25/scrapy.html.

We're using this link (https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201409040sea.htm) and we want the big table of Play by Play at the very bottom.

In the tutorial, it says the table id we want is "pbp_data" but I found the same table and the id is now "pbp," with this code

```
<table class="sortable stats_table now_sortable sliding_cols" id="pbp" data-cols-to-freeze="2">
```

I've never used Python or XPath before so I just followed the direction they said which was to do `response.xpath('//table[@id ="pbp"]')` in my scrapy shell, but for some reason, nothing is showing up when I hit enter.

Is there a problem with my understanding of XPath or am I doing something wrong with scrapy?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions are encouraged to provide a [Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), try to improve yours.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `view(response)` you'll notice that the data you are trying to scrape is commented:

```
<div class="placeholder"></div>
<!--
   <div class="table_outer_container">
      <div class="overthrow table_container" id="div_pbp">
  <table class="sortable stats_table" id="pbp" data-cols-to-freeze=2>
... -->
```

Will [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21831369/4570170) help you?

Comment: hi, thank for the response! I think actually if you scroll down some more, there's an uncommented portion that says the same thing that I'm having trouble scraping. when I search for `//*[@id="pbp"]` I can find the entire table in the element inspector. thanks again!

Comment: I did some more experimenting and I believe it has something to do with not being able to properly scrape a dynamic website. I opened the page source and am unable to find the data but in the inspect element it's there. Currently looking for ways to try to scrape dynamic data with the scrapy shell

Comment: @tigsss I assume you've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8171469/4570170)?