# Scrapy: unable to locate table or scrape data in table

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

For a group project, I am trying to scrape Salaries table within https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/allenra02.html.

I have tried multiple CSS and Xpath selectors such as

```
#all_salaries > tbody > tr:nth-child(1)
#all_salaries > tbody
#all_salaries > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.right
#all_salaries
//*[@id="all_salaries"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]
//*[@id="all_salaries"]/tbody
//*[@id="all_salaries"]
```

Code look as follows:

```
def start_requests(self):
    start_urls = ['https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/allenra02.html']

    for url in start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_season)

def parse_player(self, response): 
 response.css('#all_salaries > tbody)
```

I tried printing it out, but it keeps returning an empty list.
Other tables seem fine, except this one.

EDIT:

My final solution looks something like

```
regex = re.compile(r'<!--(.*)-->', re.DOTALL)
    salaries = response.xpath('//*[@id="all_all_salaries"]/comment()').get()
    
    if salaries:
        salaries = response.xpath('//*[@id="all_all_salaries"]/comment()').re(regex)[0]
        salaries_sel = scrapy.Selector(text=salaries, type="html")
        all_salaries = salaries_sel.css('#all_salaries > tbody > tr').extract()
```

Comment: hey @JWiryo do you still have the solution? Looked at the answer given below & it shows how to get the comment but I haven't figured out how to get any content after that...

Comment: Yup! Let me edit my quesiton

Comment: Thanks @JWiryo, because of your edit I'm now able to get the desired content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BeautifulSoup to pull out the comments then parse the table with pandas. I chose to only pull out the salary table, but you can get all the tables in the comments this way.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/allenra02.html"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

comments = soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))
tables = []
for each in comments:
    if 'table' in str(each):
        try:
            tables.append(pd.read_html(str(each), attrs = {'id': 'all_salaries'})[0])
            break
        except:
            continue
print(tables[0].to_string())
```

**Output:**

```
     Season                 Team   Lg        Salary
0   1996-97      Milwaukee Bucks  NBA    $1,785,000
1   1997-98      Milwaukee Bucks  NBA    $2,052,360
2   1998-99      Milwaukee Bucks  NBA    $2,320,000
3   1999-00      Milwaukee Bucks  NBA    $9,000,000
4   2000-01      Milwaukee Bucks  NBA   $10,130,000
5   2001-02      Milwaukee Bucks  NBA   $11,250,000
6   2002-03      Milwaukee Bucks  NBA   $12,375,000
7   2003-04  Seattle SuperSonics  NBA   $13,500,000
8   2004-05  Seattle SuperSonics  NBA   $14,625,000
9   2005-06  Seattle SuperSonics  NBA   $13,223,140
10  2006-07  Seattle SuperSonics  NBA   $14,611,570
11  2007-08       Boston Celtics  NBA   $16,000,000
12  2008-09       Boston Celtics  NBA   $18,388,430
13  2009-10       Boston Celtics  NBA   $18,776,860
14  2010-11       Boston Celtics  NBA   $10,000,000
15  2011-12       Boston Celtics  NBA   $10,000,000
16  2012-13           Miami Heat  NBA    $3,090,000
17  2013-14           Miami Heat  NBA    $3,229,050
18   Career  (may be incomplete)  NaN  $184,356,410
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because that table is actually commented out in the original source code and later added via javascript. Have a look here on how to get the comment contents: [Scrapy: Extract commented (hidden) content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21830812/scrapy-extract-commented-hidden-content)

Comment: Ah I see! Let me check it out! Thank you

Comment: Solved it! Thank you so much!